# In Blade Runner 2049, whose eye opened in the first shot?

Tags: blade-runner-2049

The opening shot of *Blade Runner 2049* shows an eye opening. The eyelashes and eyebrow are light-colored. I was searching for a person/replicant with that coloring throughout the rest of the movie but didn't find it.

**Whose eye was that?**

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I compared the shape of the eye to different members of the cast. As I was comparing photos, I realized [lens focal length](http://leggnet.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Focal-Length-Comparison-550.jpg) might throw off comparisons; the shape of an object can change depending on how close to the camera it is. I tried to take this into account as I searched.

Along with others, my initial assumption is that this eye belonged to Ryan Gosling (Officer K), but the shape of his eye didn't match at all. I ruled out anyone with *overtly* brown or blue eyes, since the iris appears to be green or green-blue. This didn't leave many other options.

Short of official confirmation on who the eye belongs to, I suspect it *might* be

### Carla Juri (Ana Stelline)

[image: Eye comparison 1]

Photo from [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm3231562/mediaindex).

There are some difficulties in this identification:

- As mentioned above, the focal length. For the film photograph to be so close, it can affect the appearance of shape and size of features (e.g. the distance between the upper eyelid and the wrinkle above it).
- The eye in the photo from the film appears to have little makeup, while the clearest photo I could find of Carla Juri's face has her wearing mascara.
- The two photos do not have the same color balance, saturation, brightness, lighting angle, etc.
- I could not find information what her eye color is. It appears close, but with such different lighting, and the lower resolution, it's difficult to tell for certain.

That said, here are the points of overlap that could support this identification:

1. A longer, curvy vein extending from the right of her iris to the lower eyelid.
2. Two small, distinct gaps in her lower eyelashes.
3. A bolder, straight vein on the far left of her eye.
4. The overall shape of her eye.

[image: Eye comparison 2]

(I heightened the contrast in the photo of Carla Juri to make it easier to see the veins in the sclera.)

Comment: Not the same eyes. Carla Juri has lightly applied mascara, not ‘prominent eyeliner.’

Comment: My apologies for not knowing the difference of makeup. I don't wear it myself.

Comment: To the person who downvoted: Pending identification of the eye from someone who worked on the film, what is wrong with this answer? How can I improve it?

Comment: I think your answer is well-thought out and convincingly presented but I still think it’s wrong. Not my downvote btw.

Answer (score 5):

I can only assume it belongs to K, since he is the main character and has pale green eyes and dirty blonde hair (Mariette also has light green iris, but she's an unlikely candidate). Another thing that supports this theory is that when Deckard looks at Rachel, he says "her eyes were green", which as we know isn't true. Where did that "green eye" idea come from? Probably from looking into K's distinguishable eyes just prior.

Just so you know, the eye from the first movie belonged to Roy Batty. That further solidifies K as the likely candidate, as K has parallels to Roy. Like Roy, K was initially a merciless murderer, and later turned out to save Deckard from a near-death experience. Not to mention, the "tears in rain" theme played for both of their deaths.

Comment: Not that I think the answer isn't good, but [Ryan Gosling's eyes are blue](https://i.pinimg.com/736x/aa/78/65/aa78651aad8667319c78e5e6627d8e6e--ryan-gosling-ryan-oneal.jpg), and the eye in the original film is supposed to belong [either to Holden (as he's running the VK test on Leon) or to no one in particular](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083658/faq#.2.1.13).

Comment: Additionally, the photo above appears to be a right eye, and the apex of the eyelid is further 'outside', right of center (viewer's left). Examining photos of Gosling's face, the apex of his eyelid is closer 'inside', which for his right eye would be left of center (viewer's right). It appears to be the wrong shape to be his eye.

Comment: but... K is asleep at the beginning of the film

Answer (score 3):

## We don't know for sure

The screenplay doesn't specify *who's* eye it is, just that it's a green eye:

> FADE IN ON:
> A GREEN EYE
> We move towards its pupil.
> <sub>-Final Shooting Script, *Blade Runner 2049* (2017), Green, M., Fancher, H.</sub>

That's it, nothing else.

### Rachael

The number one contender could actually be Rachael's. In fact, the next striking piece of green that we see is a close-up of Rachel's eye, from footage of her old Voight-Kampff test:

> A title on the record: VOIGHT-KAMPFF TEST NOVEMBER 2019
> OFFICER RICK DECKARD / SUBJECT # N6RRP40619.
> Up comes A EXTREME-CLOSE IMAGE OF...
> AN EYE
> LARGE. LOVELY. A rich green we so far haven’t seen in the
> film. AN OLD VOIGHT-KAMPFF RECORDING. The eye BLINKS.
> <sub>-Ibid.</sub>

Yes, yes, I know that in the original, Rachael's eyes were portrayed as brown, or at least not specifically *changed* from Sean Young's natural brown. But in the screenplay for 2049, her eyes are *specifically* shown to be green.

### Joi

Look, I have no idea *why* they would choose Joi's eyes, except that they thought she was relevant and super important (as do *I* for that matter, but that's a different story). However, actress Ana De Armas, who played the role of Joi, has strikingly bright green eyes that almost perfectly match the eyes in question:

[image: A photo of actress Ana De Armas. The photo is taken from close to her face, highlighting her eyes which are a bright, light green.] <sup>[img src](https://imagenesfotos.com/fotos-de-ana-de-armas/)</sup>

Look familiar?

Comment: No help from [Michael Green](https://twitter.com/andmichaelgreen/status/978131795798515713?s=20) yet, but I'll get it out of him!

Comment: Ana De Armas' eyes do look similar but I can't tell because of the color of the lashes. Darn mascara!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's from K.

```
 1. The opening "eye shot"
```

> Just as Scott began with a close-up of an quivering iris, so
>   Villeneuve choses a nervously twitching eye as one of the first images
>   we see. In each case the gaze is that of a synthesised replicant
>   shortly to have a fateful encounter. In the original, it’s on-the-run
>   Leon Kowalski, about to undergo the Voight-Kampff replicant
>   identification test. In 2049, it’s Ryan Gosling’s artificial blade
>   runner K, en route to a violent confrontation with an older generation
>   "skin-job"

from [here](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/films/0/blade-runner-2049-callbacks-references-original-movie/)